# Can Amazon SNS push notifications directly to mobile devices?

Tags: amazon-sns

The tutorial for Windows Phone 7 push notifications says that to implement Push Notifications, you need to call Microsoft Push Notification service which manages the sending of the notification to WP7 devices.

Does that imply that to send an AMZ SNS message, I need to create an intermediary web service that routes the SNS message to Microsoft Push Notification service?

What are the options for Android and iOS devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has cloud-to-device-messaging (c2dm), which is a labs project by google.  At this time it is free.  I don't know about wp7 or.  I believe iOS has their own system as well.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon has API libraries for both Android an IOS, so you can implement them directly.
See:

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/

There is also a windows/.net library that you might be able to use directly inside a windows phone.

http://aws.amazon.com/net/

I don't know anything about the windows phone platform and your on your own for that one.

Comment: So, that means if one uploads an Android app on play store hat would continue to work? On some answer I read hat only GCM services work on apps uploaded on Google Play but hat sounds absurd.

Comment: Yes, technically thats true. I have not tired to use it that way however, so I don't know what kind of service your going to get.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft forked AWS' .NET SDK to create a version for WP7.

https://github.com/Microsoft-Interop/AWS-SDK-for-WP